# OS Context Switch in ISR

Tags: embedded, operating-system

I am just eager to know how OS actually does context switch when some asynchronous event raise ISR that make higher priority task ready to run. As far as I know when CPU enter ISR it puts some of register values to the hardware stack, so how scheduler retreives those values and puts it to the task stack ? Does it access hardware stack in order to copy values that are allready preserved ? I hope I was clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you curious about?

Comment: There's one stack *per task*. For each stack, there's a stack pointer pointing to it. So basically, for the task switch, the current stack pointer is saved and the next task's stack pointer is loaded. Interestingly, the return from OS to the task's code is then done via a `RETURN` instruction and not a `JUMP` or `CALL` like one might expect.

Comment: Also, the ISR does *not* run a task. As you correctly said, it only makes a task *runnable* (taking it out of *waiting* state), so that, in the next scheduling cycle, the OS can consider the now-ready task for further execution. If and when that task runs depends on his assigned *priority*; if it has a very high priority, the OS may try and make sure it runs a.s.a.p. before any other, lower prio task gets switched to. - The actual task switching only occurs *after* the ISR finished and returned, so there's no need to copy anything from one stack to another.

Comment: @JimmyB These two nice comments should be posted as an answer imo.

Comment: The ISR has to call an OS function (the scheduler) in order to perform a context switch.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486242/how-rtos-does-task-switching-from-interrupt/28488709#28488709).

Answer (score 2):

On a Cortex-M3 processor you have the MSP (Main Stack Pointer - which is your hardware stack) and the PSP (Process Stack Pointer - which is your task stack).

On entry to an exception the stack frame is stored on the current PSP stack (in normal, non nested operation). The exception handler then switches to the MSP stack, however it can still access the PSP stack so it can store any remaining registers etc on that same PSP stack as well as any other task information it needs.

The exception can then selected the new high priority task and switch the PSP to this tasks stack and restoring the registers that is needs. It then leaves the PSP in exactly the same state as when the task was suspended so that on return from exception the rest of the stack is correctly restored.

It is more complex than this in certain situations but that is the basic operation (On ARM Cortex-M). It will be different on other processors.

I would recommend downloading FreeRTOS and looking at the various different port layers. There is a port for pretty much everything there, and the low level task switching stuff in the "portable" directories is fairly small and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not quite sure what the scope of your question is, I'll try and summarize some concepts of preemptive scheduling:

There's one stack per *task*. For each stack, there's a stack pointer pointing to it. So basically, for the task switch, the current stack pointer is saved and the next task's stack pointer is loaded. Interestingly, the return from OS to the task's code is then done via a `RETURN` instruction, and not a `JUMP` or `CALL` like one might expect.

When an ISR interrupts a running task, it will not run another task itself. As you correctly said, it only makes a task *runnable* (taking it out of *waiting* state), so that, in the next scheduling cycle, the OS can consider the now-ready task for further execution. (If and when that task runs depends on his assigned priority; if it has a very high priority, the OS may try and make sure it runs before any other, lower prio task gets switched to.)

**The actual task switching only occurs *after* the ISR finished and returned, so there's no need to copy anything from one stack to another.**

In 'simple' implementations, the ISR may just return to the task it interrupted, so that no early, 'out-of-order' context switch will occur.

Another, more complex implementation can have the ISR return to the OS instead of the interrupted task. A function like `yield()` would thus be called, giving the OS the chance to do a task switch immediately if necessary.

This, however, may require that affected ISRs get special exit instructions appended replacing the normal compiler-generated ISR code.