# How to implement hardware interrupts in uCOS II and TM4C123G (ARM M4) MCU?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, keil, rtos, ucos

## Background:

I am using **uCOS II**, **Keil uVision 5**, and a TIVA board with the **TM4C123GH6PM** MCU on it. I was given a the port for uCOS II as well as a blank project file to get started. I wrote the tasks needed and the program works correctly but now I am interested in implementing interrupts and trying to understand how they can coexist with an RTOS. This is all done **in C**.

## Issue:

Interrupts do not work; they simply don't fire up. There are instances where the other tasks won't execute either. The core issue is that I don't really understand how interrupts can coexist with the RTOS. I've written code (in both assembly and C) on baremetal where interrupts work perfectly and I fully understand how they work when there is no layer in-between the code and the cpu.

## What I've Tried:

- I read the book and reference manual that came with uCOS-II and searched for ways to implement interrupts. No mentioning whatsoever; the only thing mentioned about interrupts is how they interact with the scheduler so interrupts are only covered in the theoretical domain.
- I asked on the micrium (original vendor) forum and no reply/seems like a dead forum
- I looked at the libraries included with the uCOS port and found something useful:

  - bsp_int is the library that deals with the interrupts. BSP stands for Board Support Package and is intended to facilitate the interaction between the software and the code
  - The library has functions to register an interrupt and enable it. The rtos uses its own table of ISR handlers mapped to the NVIC of the cpu. All handlers are filtered through a generic handler. The two useful functions from this library are:

    - bsp_intVectSet which takes the interrupt trigger ID (i.e bsp_int_id_gpiof) and a pointer to the interrupt handler and registers it
    - bsp_intEn which takes the interrupt ID and enables it
- The bsp_int library is included in bsp.c which calls the initialization function (from bsp_int) for interrupts (bsp_IntInit())
- The bsp.h file is included in the main application file (app.c)
- app.c main is the entry point of the program. The main disables interrupt, initializes uCOS (i.e the kernel) creates the first/starting task called AppTaskStart, and starts multitasking (i.e gives control to the rtos and the function never returns). I'm assuming the kernel reenables interrupts since it needs those to run
- So the way the rtos works (to my understanding) is that it hijacks the systick timer so at every clock tick, the kernel is called and is able to schedule the tasks.
- AppTaskStart, which is the very first task to execute within the kernel domain, calls bsp_init (in which, bsp_IntInit is called to initialize the interrupt table and more) and performs other initialization tasks
- The way I've set up interrupts without a kernel before, was using the Tivaware library (in C) provided by TI. It has functions for creating interrupts, specifying the trigger (i.e rising/falling edge, timer overflow, etc.), and enabling them. This method works and I thought is what I should be using to set up the interrupt I want
- So I used the tivaware library to set up interrupts on one of the gpio ports (to which, mechanical switches are connected) on the rising edge. The code for this, as well as other code to start the port f peripheral, set the switches pins to input, and enable pull-ups, is included in bsp_init (bsp.c) which is called from AppTaskStart which is called from main. So far everything works perfectly, the rtos initiliazes, and all its tasks execute accordingly. When I try to move the code directly to the main and flash the program onto the board, the rtos initializes (leds blink) but then the tasks don't execute. Any ideas why that might be?
- If I add the code to also enable and register the interrupt for when the switch is closed in the same function, using code from the tivaware library, the rtos does not initialize.
- Do I need to setup/register/enable interrupts using the tivaware library as well as register and enable them using the board support package (bsp) library? The way I understand this so far is that the bsp is registering/enabling interrupts for the kernel only whereas the tivaware code is enabling them by directly writing to the registers so the latter is needed to setup the cpu portion of the interrupts and the former is needed to setup the OS portion of the interrupts. But I don't know. I really don't understand how they've designed incorporating interrupts under uCOS II. They do specify how the interrupt handler should be written and what macros to use but nothing else.

#### What should I try next? Does anybody have any experience with working with these two components (the rtos and the board)?

I am just stuck at this point and I've been playing with the code, moving stuff around, trying to find a clue/lead to solving this issue. I can't even debug the rtos because uVision does not support uCOS and I can't use step-debugging because interrupts are firing at every clock-tick and the PC is being changed constantly so the IDE can't follow it.

I know IAR Embedded Workbench has support for uCOS-II and I have the app on my laptop and I tried setting up a project but I was only given a port/starter project for Keil and I don't know how to set one up for IAR EW. The only ports on Micrium's website are for the TM4C129 series and I tried using that to start an IAR EW project but I couldn't get it to work (libraries not being linked/missing files).

#### Thank You!

Comment: Are you calling the uCOS-II function `OSIntExit()` at the end of your interrupt handlers?  Are you using nested interrupts, and if so are you using `OSIntEnter()` or `OSIntNesting`?  See the uCOS-II Reference Manual for more info on these.

Comment: [This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486242/how-rtos-does-task-switching-from-interrupt/28488709#28488709) might clarify some things about interrupts and RTOS.

Comment: There is [more good information here](https://doc.micrium.com/display/osiiidoc/Interrupt+Management) (and the following pages).  This is uCOS-III documentation but it probably mostly applies to uCOS-II as well.

Comment: @kkrambo Not using nested interrupts. I am calling OSIntEnter at the beginning and OSIntExit at the end. Honestly, I think there might be other variables in the mix:
1. Am I correct in thinking that interrupts must be configured through the regular tivaware library first and then registered and enabled through the bsp?
2. What would happen if I registered/enabled the same interrupt using both the tivaware library and the bsp?
3. One of my tasks is periodically reading the switches. Could it be that both  reading the switches and having an interrupt triggered by the switches is an issue?

Comment: @kkrambo so I've previously read the information in the second link you posted and it seems like there's conflicting information. Should I use OSIntEnter & OSIntExit even if not using nested i/pts? The example in the link doesn't use either one. Also, the example in the link states "call user ISR" in the ISR so is there an initial ISR whose sole job is to call the actual ISR? Does my ISR need to be written in asm or is C ok? (the website states asm) It just seems like the documentation on uCOS is very scattered and somewhat conflicting

Comment: 1.) I'm not familiar with Tivaware and the BSP (the BSP is part of uCOS-II?).  But I doubt that you need to setup interrupts with both.  My guess is one or the other.  2) My guess is both libraries do much the same work but you'll have to dig into the source code and study what they do in detail.  3.)  I doubt that reading the switches interferes with the interrupt.

Comment: I believe you should use OSIntExit for interrupts that can cause a context switch.  I suspect OSIntEnter is necessary only for nested interrupts.  I believe the example FAST interrupt does not use OSIntExit because it doesn't allow for a context switch because it doesn't signal or send a message to a task so there is no opportunity to change the highest priority task that is ready to run.

Comment: @kkrambo BSP is part of uCOS; it is board/architecture specific and it makes things like turning leds on/off, gpio, and other stuff, common code and easy to use (altho the tivaware library does the same). The thing I'm confused about is that the BSP is the only way to register interrupts with uCOS but it doesn't provide functions for setting them up (i.e which pin, rising/falling edge, etc) so I assumed I must do the configuration first (non-bsp way) and then register/enable (thru bsp). I looked into the source code and that's all the bsp does. So then OSIntEnter and OSIntExit (cont'd -->)

Comment: (--> cont'd) @kkrambo should not be used since I'm not using nested interrupts and my ISR handler should not be causing a context switch (i.e not calling or unlocking any other higher-priority tasks than the one currently interrupted)? Thank you again btw!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody have any experience with working with these two components (the rtos and the board)?

I'm afraid I haven't worked with uCos (but with other OSes, mainly SysBios and FreeRTOS) and I haven't worked with Tiva (but with Sitara AM335x) yet. Still, I think some hints below may be helpful for you (and apply in spite of the different implementations you are using).

> What should I try next?

These are the steps I recommend you to consider. You can put them into any order you find most helpful.

- interrupt priorities of ISRs that call RTOS library APIs must not be higher than the level that is taken into account by RTOS, otherwise the RTOS-internal states may get corrupted, and anything can happen. Please check your OS documentation.
- Please verify the position of the interrupt vector table and its contents:
  Does every vector table entry point to one of the ISR wrapper handlers provided by the RTOS, or do you also find "independent" ISR implementations? If so, what do the latter do?
  If you find pointers into third-party libraries you don't have the code for, don't give up. These can be as important...
  Even more important than including the right header to `bsp_Int...` APIs is that interrupt management of all software components runs through one unique API, e.g., the `bsp_Int...` one.
- Your assumptions about `app.c`/`main()` sound reasonable. Please make sure that you also know about every component that accesses interrupts indirectly.
- > - AppTaskStart, which is the very first task to execute within the kernel domain, calls bsp_init (in which, bsp_IntInit is called to initialize the interrupt table and more) and performs other initialization tasks

  Please check what happens if you place a breakpoint at the top of *every* task function. Then you should be able to watch all tasks start and run into its breakpoint once.
- > - The way I've set up interrupts without a kernel before, was using the Tivaware library (in C) provided by TI. It has functions for creating interrupts, specifying the trigger (i.e rising/falling edge, timer overflow, etc.), and enabling them. This method works and I thought is what I should be using to set up the interrupt I want

  You should make sure that the Tivaware library only uses interrupts in a way that is compatible to your RTOS. You can do this by RTM or reading the sources.
- > - So I used the tivaware library to set up interrupts on one of the gpio ports (to which, mechanical switches are connected) on the rising edge. The code for this, as well as other code to start the port f peripheral, set the switches pins to input, and enable pull-ups, is included in bsp_init (bsp.c) which is called from AppTaskStart which is called from main. So far everything works perfectly, the rtos initiliazes, and all its tasks execute accordingly. When I try to move the code directly to the main and flash the program onto the board, the rtos initializes (leds blink) but then the tasks don't execute. Any ideas why that might be?

  Could it be that an electronic problem at one of the controller pins connected to the interrupt starts triggering that interrupt all the time?
- > - If I add the code to [...]

  Have you tried creating a 
  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
  When you do this, you can enhance the effect by simultaneously performing
  [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/).
- > - Do I need to setup/register/enable interrupts using the tivaware library as well as register and enable them using the board support package (bsp) library? The way I understand this so far is that the bsp is registering/enabling interrupts for the kernel only whereas the tivaware code is enabling them by directly writing to the registers so the latter is needed to setup the cpu portion of the interrupts and the former is needed to setup the OS portion of the interrupts. But I don't know. I really don't understand how they've designed incorporating interrupts under uCOS II. They do specify how the interrupt handler should be written and what macros to use but nothing else.

  This sounds dangerous. I haven't worked with Tiva yet, but instead with another TI chip (AM335x). There we had a similar situation, different libraries accessing different/overlapping parts of the same system resource by means of different abstraction layers. Situation only started improving when we tidied up the mess of abstraction layers ignoring each other and ported some code to a common abstraction layering scheme.

And some PS:

- You can write your ISRs in C or assembler, as you like. Depending on the quality of your toolchain and optimisation settings, assember may yield better performance (or not at all), and by calling C APIs from assembler, some programmers tend to make new mistakes. I'd recommend to stay within C until you know in detail what is happening around your OS and IRQs.