# Context saving in ISR vs Context switching between threads

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m

Let's take the Cortex M4 processor: Whenever an ISR is triggered, it saves the R0-R3, R12 and R14 (LR) registers in it's private stack as a part of context saving; further, in cases of RTOS implementation, of context switching between two different threads, it also saves the remaining registers (that is R4-R8, R10, R11 and SP) along with the previously mentioned registers in it's private stack.

What I want to understand is why was this design made? In both ISR and RTOS scenarios, the program will continue it's execution from the point where it was interrupted after coming back. How does this design of context saving make a difference?

Comment: Most importantly it saves the return address. If that one isn't saved the program would crash upon hitting the end of the ISR. As for Cortex M specifically, I believe it stacks registers for the sole purpose of creating a callable ISR, meaning registers have to be stacked just like when calling an ordinary function.

Comment: @Ludin  Has one good point I didn't address (and not in the question).  The ISR can be 're-entrant'.  This is a separate topic from user space/mainline returns.  For the Cortex-M, re-entrant interrupts can be selectively enabled/disabled for most systems I know of.  By reentrant, low priority ISR1 (key press) is active when the death ray ISR line goes high.  If you need the death ray to be handled immediately, the key press ISR code might be deferred to handle the death ray device.  Context switch code may also need to deal with this; a reason it might be disabled (versus critical IRQ latency)

Comment: we covered this already in prior questions.  So you can use a compiled function as is for a handler no special construction. you should just ask the real questions you are after and not a series of questions (that already have answers here and in arm or other docs).   Do you have further questions on this topic?

Comment: @old_timer  If you believe there are other question that answer the topic, *Context saving in ISR vs Context switching between threads* for Cortex-M you can close the question automatically as a duplicate and they will be linked.  Often, I also think there is a duplicate, but then it ends up there is not an exact fit (or the duplicate was un-answered).  I don't recall an exact duplicate to this; there are questions on Cortex-M (RTOS) context switching .

Comment: This is the closest I could find. [How RTOS does task switching from interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486242/how-rtos-does-task-switching-from-interrupt), but it does not seem to be an exact duplicate; certainly related.  Although it is kind of an X-Y issue of not comprehending that context switches do **NOT** return to the same place like an normal IRQ.

Comment: @artlessnoise, I did it a few days ago in a comment yes?

Comment: It is also in the arm documentation, which the OP has read or it is implied that they have the docs.  (as well as being painfully obvious)(if the question is instead why did they choose this desibn decision, that has no answer and should also be closed).

Comment: to be fair one gets punished for asking too many questions at one time, this sequence of questions from the OP implies that there are more questions before we see the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

> All I wanted to understand is why was this design made? Although in both ISR and RTOS scenarios, program will continue it's execution from the point where it was interrupted after coming back. How does these design of context saving will make difference?

> In the case of RTOS implementation of context switching between two different threads, it also saves remaining registers (that is R4-R8, R10, R11 and SP) along with the previously mentioned registers in it's private stack.

The registers you cite (R4-R8,R10,R11,SP) are the 'callee saved' registers.  It means that given an interrupt handler written in 'C', these registers are naturally saved and restored.  Even between sub-functions being called within the ISR.  For the Cortex-M class CPUs, a design goal was an interrupt structure that allowed ISR to be written in 'C'.

> How does these design of context saving will make difference?

It think you have a fundamental disconnect.  **ALL** registers will change during a context switch.  So, the stack slot that was saved at the start of the ISR is garbage in a context switch.  It needs to be moved to a 'old task' context store.  All register need to be updated from the 'new task' context store.

Generally context switches may not happen.  In this case, there is not need to save the 'old task' context and a 'normal' ISR return can happen in a pre-emptive system.

[ARM Link and Frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752188/arm-link-register-and-frame-pointer) have an overview of function call machinery on a Cortex-A CPUs.  It is very similar on Cortex-M (function call machinery).  Many Cortex-A and world switching tasks are similar to the Cortex-M.  It is just a list of registers to store/restore and where.  Typically you have a 'from' and 'to' pointer with the register lists.  Ie, the context save will be part of the next context restore.  The context switch code is working within the confines of a defined ABI.  Function calls happen much more frequently than context switches; so this is what drives your observations.